# How to pivot the split column in Tableau?

Tags: split, pivot-table, tableau-api

After connecting to my **mySQL DB in Tableau**, I need to **split one column containing several comma separated values**, and then *I'd like to pivot the split columns*. 
But **after selecting those columns, I couldn't see Pivot function**. Does it mean *Pivot does not work on calculated fields*? Is there any resolution?

Comment: Please check it may be helpful to you it works with fixed  function https://community.tableau.com/thread/203315

Comment: Please provide more detail............. as I would like to suggest do it before you give data source to Tableau.

Comment: Or you could not put comma separated lists of values into a single field in your mySQL database. Sometimes it is better to clean and organize the data up front as part of ETL, even if your visualization tool is kind enough to provide some features that let you paper over uglies in your database schema at query time.